# IF body, how to less line?

Tags: javascript, if-statement, appearance

```
export function carBtnsMoveActive(boolean) {
    const btnStart = document.querySelector('.btn-start')
    const btnStop = document.querySelector('.btn-stop')

    if (boolean) {
        btnStart.disabled = false
        btnStart.classList.remove('btn-off')
        btnStop.disabled = true
        btnStop.classList.add('btn-off')
    } else {
        btnStart.disabled = true
        btnStart.classList.add('btn-off')
        btnStop.disabled = false
        btnStop.classList.remove('btn-off')
    }
}
```

Hello, can someone help to improve and shrink down this 10 lines of code? I know this, IF can appearance better but i don't have knownledge how to do. I want to write readable code which has less lines. The code works.

Comment: i don't see how it can logically be shortened very much, all the properties and values are unique per case. It's plenty readable as-is, though `boolean` could be more descriptive of the purpose.

Comment: same I don't see how you can shorten the code here. Looks fine as it is

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is asking to improve working code

Comment: Hint: `btnStart.classList.toggle("btn-off", !boolean)`

Comment: do you actually need this `btn-off` thing? you can style `button:disabled`, you know.

Comment: for the sake of shrinking down the most, it could be said that since now you may(!more on this later) count on the `[disabled]` selector, maybe the `btn-off` class could be just replaced with `button[disabled]` quite safely. Anyway it's not exactly the same thing. Or something wilder you could have the boolean argument as a data attribute on the button elements and you could just select all elements having a class starting with `btn-` and run the same callback on both passing the respective fetched data attr value. I was missing `:disabled` that I read on a further comment!

Answer (score 2):

I haven't tested this code, but this is my strategy for refactoring your code into something more concise.

```
function setEnabled(btn, isEnabled) {
  btn.disabled = !isEnabled;
  btn.classList[isEnabled ? 'remove' : 'add']('btn-off');
}

setEnabled(btnStart, !boolean)
setEnabled(btnStop, boolean)
```

Comment: This requires two function calls every time

Comment: @Samathingamajig, can you explain what you mean?  It's two function calls, yes.  Why is that a bad thing?

Comment: I'm not saying it's necessarily a *bad* thing, I'm drawing attention to a major difference in functionality between the original function and this answer's